# Can a material be created from a gameobject in Unity?

Tags: unity, game-design

I am trying to manually create snowflakes in unity, after I created a snowflake in the unity scene, is it possible to create a material out of it?

Comment: Do you mean a [Prefab](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Prefabs.html) ?

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking here. What exactly is a "snowflake" in your game? A 3d mesh? A 2d sprite? How exactly do you "create a snowflake"? And what aspects of that "snowflake" should that material have?

Comment: I just create a snowflake-look alike gameobject manually using vertical and horizontal planes. I need to convert it to a material so that i can add it to the particle system to make snow look like the snowflake I created, otherwise by default the snowflakes are just the squares.

Comment: It sounds like what you want is a snowflake *texture* — that's the 2D graphic that gives a typical particle its shape and visual detail. You could also emit mesh particles, but for a reasonably flat object like a snowflake that's probably overkill.